# $theme_option глобальная переменная в WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите поставил вот эту [тему](http://themeforest.net/item/coursat-multipurpose-wordpress-enquiry-portal/12242369) и теперь когда пытаюсь сохранить изменения в ней мне выдает вот такую [ошибку](http://prntscr.com/86coef) и сверху написано про какую то глобальную переменную. Как можно решить данный вопрос*

Comment: Вам же автор темы ответил.

Comment: а можно более развернуто, я не понимаю о чем речь идет, если я администратор сайта, как я могу зайти позже или перезагрузить страницу если это не помогает.